# ReferenceError: arr is not defined

Tags: javascript, bucle-for

Ayuda con este código:

```
function incrementarPorUno(array) {
  
 // Tu código debajo:

  for(let arr of array){
    arr += 1;
  }
  return arr;
} 

// "array" debe ser una matriz de enteros (int/integers)
// Aumenta cada entero por 1
// y devuelve el array
```

Ya logré solucionar este ejercicio con un for común, pero quería probar otra solución más corta, ¿puede solucionarse con un for in o for of? Por qué me tira error de esta forma? Alguna otra solución rápida ?
Gracias!!

El error que obtengo es:

incrementarPorUno(arr) › should return the array with each value incremented by one

```
ReferenceError: arr is not defined

  30 |     arr += 1;
  31 |   }
> 32 |   return arr;
     |   ^
  33 | }
  34 | 
  35 |
```

Comment: Ayudaría mucho que indiques el error que obtienes

Comment: ahí lo agregué!

Comment: Es por el scope donde existe arr, fuera del for será innacesible

Comment: @BetaM me da error aunque lo ponga dentro del for :'(  será porque no me retornar el array completo y solo el valor de cada vuelta?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu error está en el alcance de la variable `arr`, solo es válida para el bucle, si quieres que se quede en el contexto actual puedes usar `var`, pero solo dará un entero, te propongo que uses [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), el cual recorre los elementos del array y devuelve otro array de elementos aplicándole un criterio específico a cada elemento

Como te piden que `array` sea un array de enteros, lo mejor es usar [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) para filtrar los elementos de un array que cumplan un criterio, usando [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) para comprobar que el array sea de enteros **(Si el array siempre será de enteros puedes saltarte estas verificaciones)**

```js
function aumentarArray(a) {
  if (Array.isArray(a)) { // Comprobar si es array
    if (a.filter(e => typeof e !== "number").length === 0) {
      // Comprobar si el array es de enteros
      return a.map(e => e + 1);
      // Aumentar cada elemento por 1 y devolver el resultado
    }
  }
}

console.log(aumentarArray([1,10,15])); // [2,11,16]
```

Comment: Excelente, me sirvió tu explicación para repasar el tema de los scopes, la resolví con map para practicar y probé también resolver cambiando de lugar el return de mi solución, pero me dio error :'(